# Unable to display Menu MenuItemImage in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Currently, I'm trying to display Menu(MenuItemImage) in cocos2dx however it doesn't show up. The Sprite shows normally. I googled around but no solution. I would love to have some tips or examples from you!

```
bool GameLayer::init(int level)
{
    if (!Layer::init())
        return false;

    auto moreButton = MenuItemImage::create("more.png","more.png",[](Ref*sender){});
    moreButton->setPosition(Vec2(WINSIZE.width /2.0,WINSIZE.height / 2.0));

    this->addChild(moreButton, ZOrder::Enemy);

    auto menu = Menu::create(moreButton, NULL);
    this->addChild(menu);
    menu->setPosition(WINSIZE.width / 2.0, WINSIZE.height / 2.0);

    initBackground(); 
    return true;
}


void GameLayer::initBackground()
{
    auto bgForCharacter = Sprite::create("Background1.png");
    bgForCharacter->setAnchorPoint(Point(0, 1));
    bgForCharacter->setPosition(Point(0, WINSIZE.height));
    addChild(bgForCharacter, ZOrder::BgForCharacter);

    auto bgForPuzzle = Sprite::create("Background2.png");
    bgForPuzzle->setAnchorPoint(Point::ZERO);
    bgForPuzzle->setPosition(Point::ZERO);
    addChild(bgForPuzzle, ZOrder::BgForP);
    //TODO
}
```

The following is in the header class.

```
 enum ZOrder
    {
        BgForCharacter = 0,
        BgForPuzzle,
        Enemy,
        EnemyHp,
        Char,
        CharHp,
        Ball,
        Level,
        Result,
    };
```

Comment: what is the value of `WINSIZE` ?

Comment: It is "#define WINSIZE Director::getInstance()->getWinSize()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume `Menu` as container or parent of different type of `MenuItem`. No need to set position of `MenuItem` if you've single MenuItem, set Position of his parent(Menu).

Not add `MenuItem` to `Scene` or `Layer`, just pass in `create()` method of `Menu`. When you pass in create method it will added as child to that `Menu`.

```
bool GameLayer::init(int level)
{
    if (!Layer::init())
        return false;

    auto moreButton = MenuItemImage::create("more.png","more.png",[](Ref*sender){});

    auto menu = Menu::create(moreButton, NULL);        
    menu->setPosition(WINSIZE.width / 2.0, WINSIZE.height / 2.0);
    this->addChild(menu);

    initBackground(); 
    return true;
}
```

If you've more than one `MenuItem` in a `Menu` then we need to set position of each `MenuItem`.

MenuItem position is corresponding to his parent Menu so according to your code you set Menu at center of Screen and then you set same offset to his child so MenuItem goes at top right corner (may be not visible.)

Comment: I've updated the code. The menu does not show up. Maybe because of the ZOrder that I added to other Sprites?

Comment: your code giving me runtime exception at `auto menu = Menu::create(moreButton,NULL);` because moreButton already added. It can't be added again.

Comment: Which version of cocos2d-x you're using ? I am using v3.15